# Laravel Eloquent with 'with' and 'wherehas'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Let's say I have three databases, player, credit, and photo, linked with foreign keys:

```
player
id | name | address

credit
id | player_id | credit_status

photo
id | player_id
```

Say I want to get all players who has credit_status $status, I'd do it like this:

```
$status = 'bar';
Player::with('photo','credit')->whereHas('credit', function ($q) use ($status) {
            $q->where('credit_status', $status)->with('credit_status');
        })->paginate(15);
```

This will lists all players who has credit_status $credit, but it still lists all credits by that player regardless of the status.

The output is something like:

```
{
id: 1
name: Andrew
address: home
photo: {
          id: 2
          photo: image1
       }
credit: {
          [
              {
              id: 6
              credit_status: foo,
              id: 2
              credit_status: bar
              }
          ]
        }
},
{
id: 2
name: Mark
address: home
photo: {
          id: 5
          photo: image4
       }
credit: {
          [
              {
              id: 10
              credit_status: foo,
              id: 6
              credit_status: bar,
              id: 8
              credit_status: bar
              }
          ]
        }
}
```

I want to filter the credit in with('credit') also.
My desired output:

```
{
id: 1
name: Andrew
address: home
photo: {
          id: 2
          photo: image1
       }
credit: {
          [
              {
              id: 2
              credit_status: bar
              }
          ]
        }
},
{
id: 2
name: Mark
address: home
photo: {
          id: 5
          photo: image4
       }
credit: {
          [
              {
              id: 6
              credit_status: bar,
              id: 8
              credit_status: bar
              }
          ]
        }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just do the same filtering on the `with` (constraining eager loading):

```
$creditFilter = function ($q) use ($status) {
    $q->where('credit_status', $status);
};

Player::with(['photo', 'credit' => $creditFilter])
    ->whereHas('credit', $creditFilter)
    ->paginate(15);
```

You can save that closure and pass it to the `with` and `whereHas` so you don't have to type the same identical closure twice.

[Laravel 5.6 Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Eager Loading - Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: @RizkiHadiaturrasyid if it work for you, then you can accept it as answer. It helps future user

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I was going to accept but it said I need to wait two minutes before accepting.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter credits too then you have to also use the condition in the `credit`. Actually `whereHas()` and `with()` work independently they are not dependent on each other.

```
 $status = 'bar';
    Player::with(['photo','credit' => function($query) use ($status){

          $query->where('credit_status', $status)->with('credit_status');


    }])->whereHas('credit', function ($q) use ($status) {
                $q->where('credit_status', $status)->with('credit_status');
            })->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You only need to make conditional with the 'with' function; not with the 'whereHas' function. 

$creditFilter = function ($q) use ($status) {
    $q->where('credit_status', $status);
};

Player::with(['photo', 'credit'])
    ->with(['credit' => $creditFilter])
    ->paginate(15);
```